# Flutter: AnimatedSwitcher inside StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, animation, stream, chat

Im trying to implement an AnimatedSwitcher in my app to animate a chat that uses firebase as backend, i already seen various examples but when i try to send new messages in the chat the animation doesn't work, this is my code:

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _chats,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            !snapshot.hasError &&
            snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
          item = [];
          Map data = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
          data.forEach((index, data) => item.add({
                "key": index,
                "message": data['message'],
                "sendBy": data['sendBy'],
                "time": data['time']
              }));
          item.sort((b, a) => a["time"].compareTo(b["time"]));
          return AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: item.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return MessageTile(
                      message: item[index]['message'],
                      sendByMe: widget.user.uid == item[index]['sendBy'],
                      time: item[index]['time']);
                }),
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the "new" child is the same widget type and key as the "old" child,
> but with different parameters, then AnimatedSwitcher will not do a
> transition between them

Try giving a different key to the child (ListView) each time the StreamBuilder rebuilds

```
return AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  child: ListView.builder(
    key: ValueKey<int>(item.length), //perhaps a key based on the number of messages, so it will always be different
    reverse: true,
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemCount: item.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return MessageTile(
        message: item[index]['message'],
        sendByMe: widget.user.uid == item[index]['sendBy'],
        time: item[index]['time']);
  }),
);
```

Comment: thanks, that do the trick, but what type of transition do you recommend me to a chat stream?
default is fade transition

Comment: I suppose what you want is to animate the newest message instead of the whole list, have you tried AnimatedList? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html